# Structs in a Singleton?

Tags: ios, objective-c, multithreading, singleton, game-engine

I'm trying to write a game and currently im using Singletons to maintain the state of a game. The data structures in my singletons states are simple C structs.

- Is it a good idea for multiple objects to have the ability to write to the struct?
- What happens in the case of multiple threads?
- Any way to ensure the sanctity of my data in the singleton?

Comment: Why use a `struct`? Create a class with properties and methods to encapsulate the data and logic.

Comment: Im using a struct inside a singleton class. Or do you suggest to make the struct data a class as well?

Comment: Either make the `struct` its own class or roll the fields of the struct into your singleton class. Which ever makes more sense for your code and design.

Comment: Making it like its own class seems like a good option. What you mean by roll the fields of the struct though?